# Motion detection of a specific object in .net

Tags: .net, camera, motion-detection

I need to make a .net application where I must detect a specific object the user is holding, using a camera.

If the object must have some specific characteristics so that it can be easily recognized and detected from the surrounding space, please give me some tips (ex a green cube?)

What would be the best technique/.net library to use? I need to translate in realtime the user's hand movement and display an animation on screen accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for motion detection: find the good features(corners,ie.) and feed them into a lucas-kanada optical flow algorithm. opencv has those functions but I don't know if opencvnet has it or not.

if your object has a specific feature, like being the greenest in the scene for example, you can use thresholding. otherwise you need to use pattern recognition techniques.
pseudo code:

```
threshold1 = 128
threshold2 = 64
foreach Pixel p in Picture
 if (p.Green > 128) and (p.Red < threshold2) and (p.Blue < threshold2)
   outputImage.CurrentPixel = 255
else
   outputImage.CurrentPixel = 0
```

here you'll have your image which greens are shown as white and the rest is black

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [AForge.Net](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).
See also [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest coming up to speed on [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), [Emgu CV's](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) the .NET port I use.